# How does "edit system" of StackExchange work?

Tags: php, text, stackexchange

`StackExchange` has introduced an interesting edit system, as authors can review the edits made to his/her post, by marking the words changed (red for old words, and green for new words). How does this system work?

I think that the system does not record the list of changes/edits, but store different versions, and the markups we see as the `edit review` are the result of comparison between two versions.

But, how we can compare two texts to highlight the changes?

I wish to code it in `PHP`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219608/how-does-one-store-history-of-edits-effectively/1219805

Comment: It's usually called diff. Just google it you will find some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To highlight Codechanges you can use some Diff-Tools/Functions.

Short googling found for PHP [php-diff](https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff). There are also other tools/frameworks for other languages available on internet.